# how to show a red field under a selected car from a map with flex?

Tags: reactjs

I list cars and each row has two cars. if I select one I want to show under the selected field a box with a full width screen. it works but on the first selected item the second car goes away. Of course because I use flex with two rows with flex wrap. But how can I now show my red field under the select car where both cars are above. I show two screens one which no car is selected an the second where is selected but the second car goes aways.

```
      <section className="flex flex-row flex-wrap flex-between car-append">
        {
          car.map((el, i) => {
            let index = currentCar ? car.findIndex((e => e.id === currentCar.id)) : null;

            
            if(index === null) {
              return (
                <CarItemList 
                  key={el.id}
                  startDate={startDateParam}
                  endDate={endDateParam}
                  onClick={() => handleSetCurrentCar(el)}
                  currentCarID={currentCar && currentCar.id === el.id ? el.id : null}
                  {...el}
                />
              )
            } else {
              return (
                <>
                  <CarItemList 
                    key={el.id}
                    startDate={startDateParam}
                    endDate={endDateParam}
                    onClick={() => handleSetCurrentCar(el)}
                    currentCarID={currentCar && currentCar.id === el.id ? el.id : null}
                    {...el}
                  />
                  {
                    index === i &&
                    <section style={{height: 450, backgroundColor: 'red', width: '100%'}}>
                      <p>Test</p>
                    </section>
                  }
                </>
              )
            }
          })
        }
      </section>
```

[image]

##########################################
###########

**SELECTED SCREEN:**

[image]

#################
##########
**And I want this but this only works if the second element is selected**
[image]